# straightedge and compass construction in Hartshorne's Geometry: Euclid and Beyond

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction, axiomatic-geometry

Do you think that the following straightedge and compass construction as a single step is valid?

Given line segment AB and a point C on line L, for a given side of C, find point D such that $AB \cong CD$. Construct a circle with center $D$ and radius $CD$.

The problem here is finding that point D with a compass. We can certainly construct a circle centered around C first to find that point D, but that would require adding one more step and therefore total of 2 steps for this construction.

The context here is Exercise 13.1 of Geometry: Euclid and Beyond by Hartshorne. It claims that there exist straightedge and compass constructions in 5 steps or fewer for line segments of length $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{6}, \sqrt{7}, \sqrt{10}$ given a line segment of length 1.

Comment: This seems like 2 steps to me. Are there any of the lengths for which you think you can't get the 5-steps-or-fewer construction without doing this?

Comment: Yes I think you're right it is 2 steps. At the time I had trouble figuring out how to construct some of the radicals in 13.1, but I think I finally got all of them now.  Thanks.